# Verify whether data is missing at random (for multiple imputation)

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I'm currently working with a data set from the medical domain, in which several parameters contain missing values (up to 40% of the data). The missing data is mostly caused by some hospitals not measuring a certain parameter. For example, 23 out of 25 hospitals measure hemoglobin values. The other two hospitals do not measure it at all, hence the hemoglobin data for those patients from these hospitals is missing. I must note here that there is no inter-hospital variability between parameters.

I've read about the concepts of Missing At Random (MAR), Missing Completely At Random (MCAR) and Missing Not At Random (MNAR). I think my missing data falls under the first category; MAR. Furthermore, I assume these values can be imputated based on all other available data for these patients. It however feels dangerous to impute these values since all data for that hospital is missing.

Three questions:

1. Am I correct to assume this missing data falls under the "MAR" category? I read on the [wikipedia page of missing values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data): "Since MAR is an assumption that is impossible to verify statistically, we must rely on its substantive reasonableness."
2. Am I correct to assume that, if 1 is true, I can use multiple imputation (such as MICE) to fill in the missing values?
3. Are there ways to determine whether or not imputing these values leads to bias?

Comment: Do you have any other information in your data set, i.e. are there other variables except hemoglobin measurements?? In many, cases the rest of the variables (rest information) can give some insight into the missing mechanism.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 thanks for you response. Yes, there are many other variables, around 20-30. Could you explain how these would give me insight into the missing mechanism?

Comment: For example, imagine that you have a variable that corresponds to the weight of participants "Overweight",  "Normal", "Underweight". Also, you have a variable that corresponds to the number of calories consumed per day. People who belong to "Overweight" group might not want to give that kind of information of how many calories they consume per day. So, you can infer the missingness by looking at an observed variable.